# What is the semantic behind "all thing something" like in "all thing pet"?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I came across "all thing pet" myself in my country although it is not a native english speaking Nation and also there is a  Church Song: "All things bright and beautiful"

What I get from "all things something" is like "all thing about/on something"? if that is so why ommit the preposition?

Comment: See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252633/what-does-all-things-x-mean). _All things bright and beautiful_ is a well-known _hymn_ written in 1848. which says that God made 'everything that is bright and beautiful'. _All Thing**s** Pet_ appears to be an online store for pet food and accessories. This kind of phrase has become fairly common in recent times to describe businesses. As you say, it means _everything to do with pets_ - it isn't intended to be grammatical.

Comment: And it is always "all thing**s**", never *thing*, because *all* has to refer to a plural.